# selectOneMenu not working with method returning List<>

Tags: java, primefaces

Is there any reason for it not working with a function returning a List<>? Note that it will populate the list with the correct information. It's when sending the select publicLists.selectedList call it will fail.

The converter and everything is working like it should since the second version will work.

I am aware that you can use

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
```

But when I try to use a selectOneMenu like this it will not work

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="lista" value="#{publicLists.selectedList}" converter="allInstrumentConverter">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Välj en" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{publicLists.fetchLists()}" var="val" itemLabel="#{val.name}" itemValue="#{val}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Of course this will work since the list is prepopulated.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="lista" value="#{publicLists.selectedList}" converter="allInstrumentConverter">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Välj en" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{publicLists.allLists}" var="val" itemLabel="#{val.name}" itemValue="#{val}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Function for returning the value (skipping irrelevant request to other service)

```
try {
            JsonNode json = response.readEntity(JsonNode.class);
            allLists = mapper.readValue(json.traverse(), new TypeReference<List<AllLists>>(){});
            return allLists;

        }
```

Comment: [mcve] please... And version info

Comment: What does "it will fail" and "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: Hoeever, just a shot in the dark: You have not implemented `equals` correctly in  your class `AllLists`